# Neo4j Cypher Commands for Parent -Child Relationship

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Parent and Child records are in the same csv file with each child record having a parent id. I have loaded all nodes in Neo4j using Cypher. I am looking for Chyper commands to create parent child relationship.

Comment: Please show the structure or sample data of Csv. what are the properties by which we can identify which node is parent and which node is child.

Answer (score 1):

as @CleanBold suggests, we need a lot more information to provide better clarity, but if you have already used the csv to load all the nodes in the graph and you just need them connected. Then make a 2nd pass through your csv to create the relationships

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///records.csv' AS row
MATCH (parent:SomeLabel {id: row.parent_id}), (child:SomeLabel {id: row.id})
MERGE (parent)-[:HAS_CHILD]->(child)
```

Comment: LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///records.csv' AS row
MATCH (parent:SomeLabel {id: row.parent_id}), (child:SomeLabel {id: row.id, parent_id: row.parent_id})
MERGE (parent)-[:HAS_CHILD]->(child)